# Is it possible to select text in jquery context from a sibling element context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For instance, the code is:

```
<ul>
   <li><strong>This is a list header.</strong> And I want this text to disappear because this is not a list header!</li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript code is:

```
$('ul li').hide();
$('ul li strong').fadeIn();
```

What I am trying to achieve is to hide the text that is not inside `<strong>`.

Answer (score 5):

Try to wrap that text inside a `span` and do,

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <strong>This is a list header.</strong>
     <span>And I want this text to disappear because this is not a list header!</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('ul li >').hide().filter('strong').fadeIn();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z82EC/)

Answer (score 0):

Just like *Rajaprabhu* said, wrap that text inside a span and:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <strong>This is a list header.</strong>
     <span>And I want this text to disappear because this is not a list header!</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and the js:

```
$('ul li >').filter(':not(strong)').hide();
```